# Trying to debounce this button for when pressed

Tags: c++, arduino, lora

so I have a T-Beam. I'm trying to implement D-bounce on the button press, so that when the button is pressed there is a debounce for however long. Currently I have it working so that when the button is pressed, it will print but due to the noise from the button it prints several hundred times. I have put the debounce code in, however it doesn't work as intended and i'm not sure why.

Please have a look at my code below as I'm struggling to implement it.

```
#include <LoRa.h>

#define SS 18 // GPIO18 −− CS
#define RST 14 // GPIO14 −− RESET
#define DI0 26 // GPIO26 −− I n t e r r u p t Request
#define BAND 868E6 // 868MHz −− UK/European Radio 

const int buttonPin = 38;

int buttonState = LOW;

unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;
unsigned long debounceDelay = 200;

void setup() {

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(buttonPin, HIGH);

  // i n i t i a l i z e S e r i a l Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);



}

int counter = 0;

void loop() {

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    ( (millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay); 

    }
    else {
      Serial.println("HELLO!");
      lastDebounceTime = millis();
    }
```

Comment: `( (millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay);` is a do-nothing expression. It evaluates to a `bool` and discards the result with no obvious side effects. You probably meant to do something with the result.

Comment: What is "D-bounce"?

Comment: @septiczz Please do not vandalize your questions. The code remains a relevant part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to contain a statement that is executed but the result is never used. I am talking about the line saying `( (millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay)`. I changed your code a bit to implement proper debouncing:

```
bool buttonState = LOW, previousState = HIGH, buttonPressed = false;

void loop()
{
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    if(buttonState == HIGH)
    {
        if(previousState == LOW)
        {
            lastDebounceTime = millis();
        }
        else if(millis() - lastDebounceTime > debounceDelay && !buttonPressed)
        {
            //  this will be executed once after debouncing
            Serial.println("HELLO!");
            buttonPressed = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        buttonPressed = false;
    }
    previousState = buttonState;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the button is active low in the OP’s code, but here it seems active high